# what is Python 2.x database interface?

Tags: python, database-connection, python-2.x

I am re-writng a perl program using  python. In the perl program, it’s using perl database interface (DBI) to perform Oracle database operations. For example, DBI->connect to connect a database, and then prepare() the sql query and then execute() the query and fetch() results.  I am wondering if Python has similar official module or other means to do the same things? I am using python 2.4 and 2.6 on two different RHEL 6.3 envs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For SQLite3, there is the built-in `sqlite3` module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html
- For PostgreSQL, there is `psycopg2`: http://initd.org/psycopg/
- For MySQL, there is MySQLdb: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html
- For MS SQL Server, there is pyodbc: http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/
  ...or http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/
- For Oracle:

  - https://wiki.python.org/moin/Oracle
  - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html
  - http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net

[PEP249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), which @falsetru has mentioned, is more like an abstract description of a what a the API of a standards-conformant Python DB driver should look like. It is however in a way similar to DBI in that many (if not most or all) DB drivers for Python do have a very similar API, just like how DBI allows you to connect to many RDBMSes using a uniform API.

**PLUG:** take a look at Pony ORM also—it's an awesome new ORM with Oracle support: http://ponyorm.com.

> Currently Pony supports 4 types of databases: 'sqlite', 'mysql', 'postgresql' and **'oracle'**

It supports Python versions 2.5 or greater, but you can just use [pythonz](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz), [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) to easily install any Python version without root privileges, or [Conda](http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda).

Comment: Thanks Erik and falsetru. any module can I use for oracle?

Comment: Updated the answer; don't know why I left out Oracle initially.